# Calling a helper function that calls another function which belong in another script and it is imported into the app using source(script.R)

Tags: shiny

I expect for this code to return the value of pass, but it does not.  Where is the code incorrect?  This is part of a Shiny app.  It has a `ui <- fluidPage()` function, a `server()` function and a `helper` function outside the ui function and outside the server function.  Can the following be done?

In the `ui <- fluidPage()` function, the user is requested to upload a file. I need to extract the `filename`, therefore in the `server` function, the parameter in `observeEvent` is `input$file`, and the `fileName` is `input$file$name`.

I call the `helper` function from the `server` function.  The `helper` function is glycoPipe <- function(fileName)`and pass`input$file$name`.

`glycoPipe <- function(fileName)` receives the parameter and calls another function (pass = checkParams(fileName)`) which accepts the`fileName` parameter as well.

`function2(fileName)` is defined in the script `"utilities.R"`. This function processes the file and returns the value in the variable pass.

```
    source("utilityFunctions/utilities.R")
    #checkParams<- function(fileName){pass = TRUE} is in utilities.R
    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
          column(width = 10,
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.btn == true",
                   selectInput("value", label = h4("Do you have a params file ready to use (Y/N)?"),
                   choices = c("", "Y", "N"), selected = NULL)

                 ),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.value == 'Y'",
                   helpText(h4("Select your params file")),
                   fluidRow(
                     column(width = 10, fileInput("file", "upload the file", accept = ".tsv", placeholder = "No file selected", multiple = FALSE))
                   )
                 )
          )
      )
    )

    #helper function
    glycoPipe <-  function(filename = NULL){
        pass <- reckParams(filename)
        list(pass = pass)
    }

    server <- function(input, output, session){

      observeEvent(input$value,{
        fileName = input$file$name
        result <- function1(function2(fileName))
        value = result$pass
        output$textbox <- renderText({
          paste("Your result is", value)
        })

      })
    }

utilities.R contains
checkParams <- function{
pass = TRUE,
pass}
```

I get the right result if I do not source:

```
glycoPipe <- function(PARAMSfullFile=NULL){
list(pass = pass)
     pass<- checkParams(PARAMSfullFile)
    if (!pass) return()

}

checkParams <- function(PARAMSfullFile = NULL){
  pass = TRUE
}
server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$value,{
  result <- glycoPipe(checkParams(input$file$name))
  value = result$pass
  output$box <- renderText({
   paste("Your result is", value)
   })

 })

}
```

Comment: You need to use the `local = TRUE` argument to source in Shiny. Also your `helper` function's syntax is completely wrong. You probably meant `response <- function(...)`. I recommend that you first test it in the R console.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think I did not explain this correctly.  Let's say I have a helper function in my app: glycoPipe <- function(PARAMSfullFile=NULL){},

Comment: I have edited the previous post.  Can this be done?  can a function contain a function call to a function that it is defined in another script?

Comment: the program fails with error in system.file: ‘package’ must be of length 1.

Comment: Doing progress here.  I found that is the utilities.R file is in the same directory as the app.R file, everything works fine. However, if I save the utilities file in a subdirectory of the directory where the app.R script is it does not work.  For example: source("utilities.R") as opposed to source("/folder/utilities.R").  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: My app is in /home/user/Development/testSource and my utilities.R is in /home/user/Development/testSource/utilityFolder/utilities.R.  My working direectory -getwd()- is /home/user/testSource.  When i save the utility file in testSource where the app is stored, source("utilities.R") works fine, but if I save the utilities.R file in utilityFolder, source("home/user/testSource/utilityFolder/utilities.R") does not work.  Neither does source("testSource/utilityFolder/utilities.R")

Comment: It finally worked! source("~/Development/testSource/UtilityFoler/utilities.R",chdir = TRUE)